# Closed questions with education value

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I saw a question [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656432/why-abstract-class-is-faster-than-interface-in-c) which was closed because it was "not a question". I do think, that it's incomplete and vague but I think it's not a bad question at all. The question indicates that the poster is just started using .NET and possible OO development and doesn't fully understand the difference between abstract classes and interfaces. I was in the same shoes back then, when I learned .NET from book (and grasped OO for the first time). I think there is a legitimate answer for this question: that the difference between them is marginal (if there is - but could be as they don't compile to the same IL code) and comparing their performance is meaningless. They could be used for a similar reason (e.g. heterogenous collections), but this is not the essence of using them: it's not random that they are different language elements. I think this has more educational value, than closing a question with comments that are not pointing to the right direction - the point of SO is knowledge transfer.

Edit:
The question was deleted after I posted my message, I don't know by who and why.

Comment: `Its another question that the poster doesn't know (or doesn't want to use) the answer button.` Small tip: if you come here to seek help or discuss a topic, it's bad if you close with a side blow against the community.

Comment: Sorry, I don't meant my question to be a side blow against the community. Maybe my english is not as good as it should be to express what I meant.

Comment: I understood that sentence as "people don't know how to answer it or don't want to answer so they close it instead".

Comment: No. I meant that the user had 5 questions answered before, but neither answer was marked as answered: the poster don't use mark as answer button, however I tried to give a meaningful answer so the post at least has educational value. This last side note sentence had nothing to do with closing.

Comment: In that case I apologize and suggest you remove that sentence at all, because acceptance rate has *nothing* to do with closed or deleted questions and vice versa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is a trap for endless discussion.  It doesn't give enough details to be meaningful.  It posits an assumption that is likely to be untrue without giving any context or citing a source for a condition under which it may be true. Under such conditions it's likely that any answers would be pure speculation or some form of "you're wrong."  The latter wouldn't be so bad, except there's not enough information to even show the poster why they're wrong (again, without speculating).  You can see this just from the few comments that are on it, including yours.

Comment: This is an explanation, that I could agree with. Thank you.

Comment: After reading the first sentence I'm missing a big picture of Admiral Ackbar in this answer!

Answer (score 9):

For users under 10K who can't see the question:

> **why abstract class is faster than interface in c#?**
>
> why abstract class is faster than interface in c#? I have search this question in internet but don't find any satisfactory answer. Please provide me answer.

This is a poorly asked question for several reasons.  The main reasons it got closed and deleted as "not a real question" is that it's based on an unsupported premise (*is* an abstract class faster?) and it shows a lack of research effort on the part of the original poster.

There are several things you can do with a bad question to make it better:

1. Vote to close it and encourage the OP to give more details.
2. Edit it yourself to transform it into a better question.
3. Search to see if the question is already asked and answered.  Provide a link and vote to close as a duplicate so at least the OP gets an answer.
4. Ask your own related question if the original is a lost cause. (As long as it isn't just a duplicate of the original with improved grammar and spelling.  Do a little research and add something that should have been included in the original question but wasn't.)
5. Answer it anyway.  Often an extremely good answer to a bad question will prompt others to improve the question rather than voting to delete it.